# Redshift - How to group by max() on an array field

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift

I have a table like this :
metric is a super type, built with the array() function within redshift

| user | metrics |
| --- | --- |
| red | array(2021, 120) |
| red | array(2020, 99) |
| blue | array(2021, 151) |

I would like to do :
select user, max(metrics) from table group by user

and get this :

| user | metrics |
| --- | --- |
| red | array(2021, 120) |
| blue | array(2021, 151) |

Sadly using this query, I only get null values

Do you know how to handle that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what `metrics` looks like.  Is it a string?  Redshift doesn't support arrays.

Comment: metric is a super type, built with the array() function within redshift

Comment: . . You need to explain that clearly *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Redshift Spectrum, the logic is very similar to [unnest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html) an array field when you query an external schema.

In your case, the query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT t.user, max(metric)
FROM my_schema.my_table as t, t.metrics as metric
GROUP BY 1
```

If the array contains types other than numerical ones, you can simply cast it to int or double like:

```
max(metric::int)
```

In this way, pure string such as `"hello world"` are considered as null, but string like `"33333"` is converted to int.

Comment: It seems here it would only send back the maximum value within the array for each user  :

| red  | 2021  |
 and 
| blue | 2021  |

It may be dangerous if the second element of array would have been a string for exemple (which would be considered as the max value)

Comment: @alankar I updated the answer to handle that case